# How can i make the main Thread as Daemon Thread in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon

I want to make the main thread as daemon thread but it show me `IllegalThreadStateException`.
Is there any way to do that?

```
public class DeamonThreads {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Main Started");
        System.out.println("Thread type deamon = " + Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());
        Thread.currentThread().setDaemon(true);
        System.out.println("Thread type deamon = " + Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());
        System.out.println("Main End");
    
    }
}
```

Output

```
Main Started
Thread type deamon = false
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
     at java.lang.Thread.setDaemon(Thread.java:1367)
     at com.threads.DeamonThreads.main(DeamonThreads.java:8)
```

Comment: why you want to do that?

Comment: What do you think [_This method must be invoked before the thread is started._](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon-boolean-) means?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main thread cannot be set as daemon thread. Because a thread can be set daemon before its running and as soon as the program starts the main thread starts running and hence cannot be set as daemon thread.

***As given in javadocs...***

```
public final void setDaemon(boolean on)
```

Marks this thread as either a daemon thread or a user thread. The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads.

**This method must be invoked before the thread is started.**

Parameters:
    on - if `true`, marks this thread as a daemon thread

Throws:

- `IllegalThreadStateException` - if this thread is alive
- `SecurityException` - if `checkAccess()` determines that the current
  thread cannot modify this thread.

Answer (score 4):

As others already have pointed out, you can not do that, but what is the *real* problem that you want to solve?

There is nothing special about the main thread, so why not get rid of it?  Would this work for you?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...create at least one non-daemon thread...
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        daemon_main(args);
    });
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
}

public static void daemon_main(String[] args) {
    ...do whatever else main() did...
}
```